# nest all columns by row

Tags: r, tidyr

Here is a reproducible example where I have used an auxiliary column (temp) to generate the nested `data` column.

How can I get the same result without using an auxiliary column? I tried using `group_by_all` but it didn't work. (So, I'm also not sure that I understand what the use of the group_by_all function is)

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    Var1 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 
             2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L,
             0L, 1L, 2L, 3L),
    Var2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
             2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    Var3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
             0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
             1L, 1L,1L, 1L)
  ),
  .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3"),
  out.attrs = structure(
    list(
      dim = c(4L, 3L, 2L), 
      dimnames = structure(
        list(
          Var1 = c("Var1=0","Var1=1", "Var1=2", "Var1=3"), 
          Var2 = c("Var2=0", "Var2=1","Var2=2"), 
          Var3 = c("Var3=0", "Var3=1")), 
          .Names = c("Var1","Var2", "Var3")
        )
      ),
    .Names = c("dim", "dimnames")
  ), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-24L)
)

df$temp <- 1:nrow(df)
df %>% group_by(temp) %>% nest %>% select(-temp)
```

Comment: Any reason you want to do this instead of storing each row in a list?

Comment: I want to use dplyr::mutate() then, to operate on this list-column. An approach recommended in bullet 3 here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrrlyr/news.html

Comment: You can move the `temp` assignment inside the `group` variable, but you will still have to remove it at the end: `df %>% group_by(temp = 1:n()) %>% nest() %>% select(data)`

Comment: `group_by_all` doesn't work because it groups by all _columns_, not _rows_

Comment: One would think that `df %>% rowwise() %>% nest()` should work, but it doesn't. `rowwise()` doesn't seem to be in favor in the `tidyverse`.

Comment: rowwise is "still maintained" (https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4294) but not "actively developped" (https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3144). Its descriptions says it's made to be used with `do` while its details say its main use is `summarize` or `mutate`. `nest` is not mentioned though I would like you have expected it to work.

Comment: Definining `nest.rowwise_df` makes it possible though, see the last option of my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Here are 4 solutions

---

I designed a package called [*tags*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/tags) (github only for now) which has a function `grouping_by` wrapped around `dplyr::group_by` that permits grouping with an adverb/decorator/function operator behavior, it does the ungrouping too. When grouping by an unnamed expression the temp column is not kept and you get a more compact syntax, hopefully close enough to what you're looking for :

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/tags")
library(tidyverse)
library(tags)
df %>% grouping_by(vars(row_number()))$nest()
#> # A tibble: 24 x 1
#>    data            
#>    <list>          
#>  1 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  2 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  3 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  4 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  5 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  6 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  7 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  8 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  9 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#> 10 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#> # ... with 14 more rows
```

If we name the temp variable, it is kept :

```
df %>% grouping_by(vars(X =row_number()))$nest()
#> # A tibble: 24 x 2
#>        X data            
#>    <int> <list>          
#>  1     1 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  2     2 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  3     3 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  4     4 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  5     5 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  6     6 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  7     7 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  8     8 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  9     9 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#> 10    10 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#> # ... with 14 more rows
```

---

Here's another workaround, avoiding `nest` altogether :

```
df %>% as_tibble() %>% split(.,1:nrow(.)) %>% tibble(data =.)
#> # A tibble: 24 x 1
#>    data            
#>    <list>          
#>  1 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  2 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  3 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  4 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  5 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  6 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  7 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  8 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  9 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#> 10 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#> # ... with 14 more rows
```

You might not need the `as_tibble()` step, I used it to get the exact same output, without it you'd get regular data.frames inside of your tibble list column.

---

And a 100% base way :

```
df2 <- data.frame(data = 1:nrow(df)) # initiate with proper number of rows
df2$data <- split(df, 1:nrow(df))    # assign list column
```

Since an answer focuses on efficiency, this would be more efficient:

```
structure(list(data = split(df, rn <- seq_len(nrow(df)))),  
          row.names = rn, class = "data.frame")
```

---

create `nest.rowwise_df` do be able to use `nest()` with `rowwise()` and make @cj-yetman's idea possible:

```
nest.rowwise_df <- function(data, ..., .key = "data") {
  df %>% group_by(`*temp*` = row_number()) %>% nest() %>% select(-`*temp*`) 
}

df %>% rowwise() %>% nest()
#> # A tibble: 24 x 1
#>    data            
#>    <list>          
#>  1 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  2 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  3 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  4 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  5 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  6 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  7 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  8 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#>  9 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#> 10 <tibble [1 x 3]>
#> # ... with 14 more rows
```

Or for the same result using the package *tags* from 1st answer:

```
using_rowwise$nest(df)
```

Comment: modified to use `row_number()` whenever possible as it's more elegant and robust, inspired by Ronak's answer.

Answer (score 8):

We could use `group_split` to split on every row and use `nest` on each row.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_split(row_number(), keep = FALSE) %>%
  map_df(nest)

# A tibble: 24 x 1
#   data            
#   <list>          
# 1 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 2 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 3 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 4 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 5 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 6 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 7 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 8 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 9 <tibble [1 × 3]>
#10 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# … with 14 more rows
```

With `keep = FALSE` we do not include the grouping column which is `row_number()` here.

Now instead of `row_number`, we can use different variations to split it by row.

```
#Option 2
df %>% group_split(1:nrow(df), keep = FALSE) %>% map_df(nest)

#Option 3
df %>% group_split(seq_len(n()), keep = FALSE) %>% map_df(nest)

#Option 4
df %>% group_split(seq_len(nrow(df))) %>% map_df(nest)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `purrr::transpose`,
which is somewhat intuitive,
yet it makes my head spin when I try to understand the logic behind it:

```
tibble(data = lapply(transpose(df), as_tibble))
```

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

Nesting probably isn't the right strategy for your data, assuming your real data resembles your example data. If you insist on nesting, and your dataset is large, doing it with `split` is more efficient than doing it with `transpose`.

#### A `nest` use case

I really don't think `nest` is the right choice here. A dataframe with one list-column of single-row dataframes is basically the same as a dataframe with normal rows, except the rows are obscured.

The use case described on the page you [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrrlyr/news/news.html) to almost certainly requires the inclusion of a grouping variable - something like your `temp` variable – to nest by. An example: With the "diamonds" dataset, nest by `color`. Then compute models for each sub-dataframe using `mutate` + `map`. Then unnest `model`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

theme_set(theme_minimal())

dia_mods <- diamonds %>% 
    nest(-color) %>% 
    mutate(model = map(data, ~ lm(price ~ carat + clarity, .) %>% augment)) %>% 
    unnest(model)
```

The advantage is that, after unnesting, the model data is still associated with the grouping variable, which makes the data easier to use in ggplot, etc. If you drop the grouping variable there will be nothing to differentiate the unnested data, which would make something like this impossible:

```r
dia_mods %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = .fitted, color = clarity)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    facet_wrap(~ color) # facet by same grouping variable used to nest
```

[image: parallel slopes]

#### Benchmarking various strategies

If you are still set on using `nest` with your dataframe, then consider the following benchmarks, which I ran using your original dataframe:

[image: benchmarks]

Here's an explanation of the benchmarked methods:

- **base_r** = Moody_Mudskipper's base R solution.
- **split_tib** = `split(as_tibble(df), 1:nrow(df))`, creates list of dataframes. I'm adding this because I think it makes more sense, in your case, to just create a list.
- **split_df** = Same as split_tib, but without `as_tibble`.
- **split_tib_tib** = Moody_Mudskipper's "workaround" where he splits a tible and adds it to a tibble.
- **split_tib_df** = Same as split_tib_tib, but without `as_tibble`
- **transpose** = Alexis' very cool answer.
- **assign_temp** = Your original solution.

As you can see, the most efficient solutions involve splitting tibbles or dataframes, and the most popular answer is also one of the least efficient. This is because transposing data is computationally costly. It shouldn't matter too much for your dataframe, but I would avoid it when working with larger datasets.

The picture becomes clearer when we compare the different strategies using larger datasets. I benchmarked each method using datasets with 1x, 25x, 50x, 75x, 100x, and 125x more rows than yours:

[image]

It's clear that methods utilizing `split` are more more efficient, and that using `transpose` comes at a high computational cost. That said, it looks like the `transpose` method is losing steam at a greater rate than the others, which isn't really true. In reality, the `transpose` method is consistently ~7x slower than the fastest methods, independent of dataset size. This becomes clearer when we transform the x any y axes:

[image]

It's also worth noting that the performance of your solution (with `temp`), despite being fairly slow with smaller datasets, approaches the performance of the most efficient solutions as dataset size increases.

Comment: Thank you. Could you include Ronak Shah's solution in your analysis, or maybe provide us some of the code you have used?

Comment: @Brani unfortunately I don't have the time right now. I used the microbenchmark library to benchmark each answer, in case you're interested. Just convert the output to a dataframe using `as.data.frame` to use it in ggplot. I think Ronak Shah's answer is probably similar to split_tib_tib performance wise.

Answer (score 2):

Within `dplyr`, one can use `rowwise()` and `do()` like:

```r
df %>% rowwise %>% do( nest(data.frame(.)) ) %>% ungroup

# or with less parentheses
df %>% rowwise %>% do( data.frame(.) %>% nest ) %>% ungroup

# test identical with `purrr::transpose`
identical(
  df %>% rowwise %>% do(nest(data.frame(.))) %>% ungroup
  ,      
  tibble(data = lapply(transpose(df), as_tibble))
)

# [1] TRUE
```

where `rowwise()` will group `data.frame` by row, and present each group (row) as a named list.

In general, these "rowwise-groups" are "visible" only to statements inside a few functions like `do()` and `mutate()`, for example:

```r
df %>% rowwise %>% nest  # this nest will apply on the entire tibble

# # A tibble: 1 x 1
#   data             
#   <list>           
# 1 <tibble [24 × 3]>
```

A trick to view what gets passed over the pipe `%>%` is to `str()` it, despite this will cause error message as `do()` expect functions inside it returns a `data.frame`.

```r
df %>% rowwise %>% str(.)

# Classes ‘rowwise_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 24 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Var1: int  0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 ...
#  $ Var2: int  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
#  $ Var3: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  - attr(*, "out.attrs")=List of 2
#   ..$ dim     : int  4 3 2
#   ..$ dimnames:List of 3
#   .. ..$ Var1: chr  "Var1=0" "Var1=1" "Var1=2" "Var1=3"
#   .. ..$ Var2: chr  "Var2=0" "Var2=1" "Var2=2"
#   .. ..$ Var3: chr  "Var3=0" "Var3=1"

df %>% rowwise %>% do(str(.))

# List of 3
#  $ Var1: int 0
#  $ Var2: int 0
#  $ Var3: int 0
# List of 3
#  $ Var1: int 1
#  $ Var2: int 0
#  $ Var3: int 0
# ...
# Error: Results 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... must be data frames, not NULL
# Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

Because `tidyr::nest()` takes a `data.frame`, while `rowwise` pass a named list, we need to coerce `list` to `data.frame` use, for example, `data.frame()`, which results in the answer above.

---

If the purpose is to apply `dplyr::mutate()` on the newly created list-column, one could avoid `nest()` at all, simply using `dplyr::mutate()` after `rowwise`, with variable names, like:

```r
df.raw %>% rowwise %>% mutate(data = tibble(Var1, Var2, Var3) %>% list)

# Source: local data frame [24 x 4]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
# # A tibble: 24 x 4
#     Var1  Var2  Var3 data            
#    <int> <int> <int> <list>          
#  1     0     0     0 <tibble [1 × 3]>
#  2     1     0     0 <tibble [1 × 3]>
#  3     2     0     0 <tibble [1 × 3]>
#  4     3     0     0 <tibble [1 × 3]>
#  5     0     1     0 <tibble [1 × 3]>
#  6     1     1     0 <tibble [1 × 3]>
#  7     2     1     0 <tibble [1 × 3]>
#  8     3     1     0 <tibble [1 × 3]>
#  9     0     2     0 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 10     1     2     0 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# # … with 14 more rows

# compare the newly generated column `data` with `nest` generated
identical(
  ( 
    df.raw %>% rowwise %>% mutate(data = tibble(Var1, Var2, Var3) %>% list) 
    %>% select(data) %>% ungroup
  )
  ,      
  tibble(data = lapply(transpose(df), as_tibble))
)

# [1] TRUE
```

When combined with a functional programming style and `dplyr::unnest()`, we could, for example, generate a table to demonstrate [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem).

Given a `data.frame` with columns `Var1`, `Var2`, `Var3` as `x`, `y`, `z`, for each row, adding columns `x^2`, `y^2`, `z^2`, `n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2`.

```r
three.square = function(x, y, z) {
  tibble(
    x^2,
    y^2,
    z^2,
    n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2
  )
}

df %>% rowwise %>%
   mutate(three.square = three.square(Var1, Var2, Var3) %>% list)

# Source: local data frame [24 x 4]
# Groups: <by row>
#  
# # A tibble: 24 x 4
#     Var1  Var2  Var3 three.square    
#    <int> <int> <int> <list>          
#  1     0     0     0 <tibble [1 × 4]>
#  2     1     0     0 <tibble [1 × 4]>
#  3     2     0     0 <tibble [1 × 4]>
#  4     3     0     0 <tibble [1 × 4]>
#  5     0     1     0 <tibble [1 × 4]>
#  6     1     1     0 <tibble [1 × 4]>
#  7     2     1     0 <tibble [1 × 4]>
#  8     3     1     0 <tibble [1 × 4]>
#  9     0     2     0 <tibble [1 × 4]>
# 10     1     2     0 <tibble [1 × 4]>
# # … with 14 more rows

# to "expand" the list-column, use `dplyr::unnest()`
df %>% rowwise %>% 
   mutate(three.square = three.square(Var1, Var2, Var3) %>% list) %>% 
   unnest(three.square)

# # A tibble: 24 x 7
#     Var1  Var2  Var3 `x^2` `y^2` `z^2`     n
#    <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#  2     1     0     0     1     0     0     1
#  3     2     0     0     4     0     0     4
#  4     3     0     0     9     0     0     9
#  5     0     1     0     0     1     0     1
#  6     1     1     0     1     1     0     2
#  7     2     1     0     4     1     0     5
#  8     3     1     0     9     1     0    10
#  9     0     2     0     0     4     0     4
# 10     1     2     0     1     4     0     5
# # … with 14 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

We can `split` by sequence of rows

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  split(seq_len(nrow(.))) %>% 
  map_dfr(nest)
# A tibble: 24 x 1
#   data            
#   <list>          
# 1 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 2 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 3 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 4 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 5 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 6 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 7 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 8 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 9 <tibble [1 × 3]>
#10 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# … with 14 more rows
```

---

Or another option is `pmap`

```
df %>% 
   pmap_dfr(., ~ tibble(...) %>% 
                    nest)
# A tibble: 24 x 1
#   data            
#   <list>          
# 1 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 2 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 3 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 4 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 5 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 6 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 7 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 8 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 9 <tibble [1 × 3]>
#10 <tibble [1 × 3]>
# … with 14 more rows
```

Comment: Isn't this just option 4 from Ronak?

Comment: @Axeman He should `group_split` which could get deprecated while I used `split` from `base R` which would remain

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain the 3 dots in tibble?

Comment: df is data.frame which is a special case of named list. is passed to `pmap`. When a named list is passed to pmap, it passes for each iteration the named elements to the function argument. When using a formula this formula is converted to function whose first argument is `...`. See `?purrr::as_mapper` and `?rlang::as_function`. These dots are passed directly to tibble, so It's like having `tibble(Var1=0, Var2=0, Var3=0)` for the first element and so on

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.   got same result

```
library(purrr)
tibble(data = map(split(df,1:nrow(df)),tibble) )
```

or more elegant using plurrrlyr

```
library("purrrlyr")
df %>% by_row(tibble,.to="data") %>% select(data)
```